# Event to use in an Expert Advice that triggers when a new bar gets created

Tags: mql4, mt4

Is there any event to use in an Expert Advice that triggers when a **new bar is created**?

I think `OnChartEvent`, `OnTick`, `OnTimer` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, the named handlers do something else

As per `MQL4` documentation, built-in `OnTick()`, `OnTimer()` et al functions, are pre-defined handlers.

If needed, may try to create one's own, using built-in szstem variable **`Bars`** ( `iBars()` is rather a heavyweight alternative ):

```
bool aNewBarEVENT(){
     static  int anAlreadyObservedBarCOUNT = EMPTY;    // .INIT
     if ( Bars > anAlreadyObservedBarCOUNT ){          // .TEST
                 anAlreadyObservedBarCOUNT = Bars;     // .UPD
                 return( True );                       // .ACK
     }
     return( False );                                  // .NACK
}
```

### Usage:

[image]

Comment: Thank you again, user3666197 !!